# How to Transfer data from BroadcastReceiver to Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am making an app, its for polling through SMS. What I want is if someone says "yes" I get a +1 on my yes count and similarly for the "no" case, and I want to this to be done in background, so I am using service. and show the end result on my `MainActivity`. I tried, and made the following code::
BroadcastReciver

```
/*Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[]  msg = null;
        String body = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                body = msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();              
            }
        }*/

        String body = "yes";
        if(body.equals("YES") || body.equals("yes")|| body.equals("y") || body.equals("Y")){
            Intent yes = new Intent(context,PollCounter.class);
            yes.putExtra("yes", true);
            yes.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(yes);
            context.stopService(yes);
        }
        else if(body.equals("NO") || body.equals("no")|| body.equals("n") || body.equals("N")){
            Intent no = new Intent(context,PollCounter.class);
            no.putExtra("no", true);
            no.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(no);
            context.stopService(no);
        }
        else {
            Intent invalidMsg = new Intent(context,PollCounter.class);
            invalidMsg.putExtra("invalidMsg", true);
            context.startService(invalidMsg);
        }
    }

}
```

There is a problem in the BroadcastReceiver also, I get a " E/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.atiffarrukh.smspolling.SMSBroadcastReciever: java.lang.NullPointerException" Error, when i uncomment the following

```
/*Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[]  msg = null;
            String body = "";
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                    body = msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();              
                }
            }*/
```

Dont get the reason, I used this code before and it was working.

In the `Service` ::

```
boolean yes = intent.getBooleanExtra("yes", false);
        boolean no = intent.getBooleanExtra("no", false);
        boolean invalidMsg = intent.getBooleanExtra("invalidMsg", false);

        if (yes) {
            yesCount++;
            Intent intentYes = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intentYes.putExtra("yesCount", yesCount);
            startActivity(intentYes);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "yes is recvd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (no) {
            noCount++;
            Intent intentNo = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intentNo.putExtra("yesCount", noCount);
            startActivity(intentNo);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no is recvd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            invalidMsgCount++;
            Intent intentInavalidMsg = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intentInavalidMsg.putExtra("yesCount", invalidMsgCount);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid is recvd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

I tried to use `Bundle b = intent.getExtras();` but I am not sure how to use it, and what should I initialize `intent` with.

### Thanks...

P.S: I am new to android. Sorry if my question is a bit weird or my coding seems strange.

Comment: post full logcat here always .//

Comment: Thanks, that problem is solved... and I'll post logcat in future... what about the data transfer.. Please need help on that...

Comment: Seems your question are really 2 separate questions. One of them has been answered. Perhaps you need to edit the post to clarify what the other problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you forgot

```
msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pduArray [i]);
```

in your cycle.

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
         msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pduArray [i]);
         body = msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();              
}
```

otherwise `getMessageBody()` indeed returns `null`

Comment: thanks... that solved of one my problem... I really forgot that... Please guide me about the data transfer from BroadcastReciver to Service...

Comment: the main problem was how to get data from `BroadcastReceiver` to `Service`.. I am not able to get the data... I dont know how to do that...